# WCF Auto casting return types?

Tags: wcf, windows-8

I am working on an app for Win8, and using a Service Reference of WCF.
In my service there is a method called GetAllCatagories(), which returns List.
When I am calling this method using the Client it returns ObservableCollection
(actually a Task of it).
Why it is so? What to I have to do in order to get the return type I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building a service reference for a Windows 8 Store application (which I assume you meant) all service calls are asynchronous, so the Task return type you are seeing is because of that requirement. In your code, you will typically use the [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx) keyword and then the return value will indeed be the ObservableCollection.

ObservableCollection is the default, however, when you create the Service Reference you can opt for a different return type in the proxy object, via the Advanced... tab:

[image]

You can convert an ObservableCollection to a List as well via one of the overloaded List constructors.